# Get highest/lowest average in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I would like to know the highest and lowest average in a table based on a range of specific values I don't know it that is clear, so I made an image like shown in red.

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work. Thank you for helping me out!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I add an extra column E, enter formula "=SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D)/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)" in E2 and pull down to get the averages first.

[image]

For the highest one, enter the formula "=MAX(E:E)" in G3, to get the data in Column A, I enter formula "=VLOOKUP(G3,IF({1,0},$E2:$E31,$A2:$A31),2,FALSE)".

[image]

For the lowest one, I enter the formula "=MIN(E:E)" in H3, pull G3 to right to get the data of Column A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Emily for your input.

I used the =SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D)/COUNTIF(A:A,A2) function in E2 for averages (which I can hide in formatting by setting it the same color as the background) and =MIN/MAX(E:E) for the numbers. Though the VLOOKUP doesn't seem to ever work with me for some reason, I worked around that and used =OFFSET(INDEX(E:E),MATCH(MIN/MAX(E:E),FALSE)),0,-4) to get the text above the number.

Funnily enough, I found out thanks to your reply that I made a mistake for my example image.
[Yvon actually leads the highest average value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BOoL.png).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use VLOOKUP.
Use the formulas from this link:
https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-using-vlookup-with-min-max-and-average/